# How to host two WCF services with .net.tcp binding in windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

i want to host two services

1. Service 1 (located on D Drive)
   process data based on configuration configured in xml
   net.tcp://ServerIP/Pune_service
2. Service 2 (located on E Drive)
   process data based on configuration configured in xml
   net.tcp://ServerIP/Mumbai_service

now i tried to host these services **with net.tcp binding in two different Windows Service**
Windows service 1 Started Successfully
but when tried to start second windows service i'am getting Error i.e.
AddressAlreadyInUseException

```
  string httpBaseAddress = "http://" + _szServerIP + "/" + _szCurruntLocation + "_FileServer";
                string tcpBaseAddress = "net.tcp://" + _szServerIP + "/" + _szCurruntLocation + "_FileServer";


                Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri(httpBaseAddress), new Uri(tcpBaseAddress) };
                m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService.CalcServiceClient), adrbase);

                ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                //mBehave.AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
                m_svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

                BasicHttpBinding httpb = new BasicHttpBinding();
                m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.ICalcService), httpb, httpBaseAddress);
                m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");


                NetTcpBinding tcpb = new NetTcpBinding();
                tcpb.MaxConnections = 10;
                tcpb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                tcpb.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                tcpb.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                tcpb.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                tcpb.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                tcpb.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                tcpb.PortSharingEnabled = true;

                m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.ICalcService), tcpb, tcpBaseAddress);
                m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
                m_svcHost.Open();


                Console.WriteLine("Service is live now at : {0}", httpBaseAddress);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: i tried all solutions from Google but didn't worked. i'm posting my Code also Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.addressalreadyinuseexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for AddressAlreadyInUseException.

I think you may remove;

```
m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
```

You are trying to add a second IMetadataExchange contract for tcp binding.

Also you need to add;

```
mBehave.HttpGetEnabled = true;
```

to get mex information.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I 've updated my Code as per your suggestions but i'm getting Same Error ..

Comment: It seems you also use same port for each service.  Even though port sharing is enabled, it gets the same error. I've tried your code and if I change the port of the service, It worked for me.

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. can we change the TCP Port number.How?

Comment: for example; string tcpBaseAddress = "net.tcp://" + _szServerIP + "/" + _szCurruntLocation + "_FileServer"; can be string tcpBaseAddress = "net.tcp://" + _szServerIP + " :8888" +"/" + _szCurruntLocation + "_FileServer";

Comment: i tried this already .for this i'm getting Error: TCP error 10013

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,MexTcpBinding disable the port sharing. Which means that:

```
Binding mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
CustomBinding mexBinding2 = new CustomBinding(mexBinding);
mexBinding2.Elements.Find<TcpTransportBindingElement>().PortSharingEnabled==false //true
```

Here is an article worth reading.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/drnick/2006/08/23/an-unanticipated-addendum-for-certain-mex-scenarios/
I suggest you could write the custom binding, and then add the binding to the mex endpoint.

```
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            TcpTransportBindingElement transport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
            transport.PortSharingEnabled = true;
            CustomBinding binding1 = new CustomBinding(encoding, transport);
            m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), tcpb, tcpBaseAddress);
            m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), binding1, "mex");
```

Here is related issue on this topic.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/praburaj/2012/10/16/nettcpbinding-mextcpbinding-sharing-same-port-throws-addressalreadyinuseexception-on-upgrade-to-net-4-5/

you could also comment the following lines to ensure that codes run correctly.

```
tcpb.MaxConnections = 10;
tcpb.PortSharingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... i have made the Changes suggested by you... but i'am getting error as  AddressAlreadyInUseException. The transport manager failed to listen .